# How can I stop CALayers from animating?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, core-animation, calayer

I've created a bunch of sublayers within my view, populating each one with a graphic, so effectively they are sprites. However, when I call `[lineLayer setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5] forKeyPath:@"transform.scale"]` it appears to 'tween' to that size instead of just appearing at the new scale.

Is there any way of switching off this behaviour? I just want to change the scale directly.

Thanks!

:-Joe

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ahhh I just answered my own question... I keep doing that on here!

From the help:

> You can temporarily disable layer
>   actions when changing layer property
>   values by setting the value of the
>   transaction’s
>   kCATransactionDisableActions to true.
>   Any changes made during the scope of
>   that transaction will not result in an
>   animation occurring. Listing 2 shows
>   an example that disables the fade
>   animation that occurs when removing
>   aLayer from a visible layer-tree.

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setValue:(id)kCFBooleanTrue
                 forKey:kCATransactionDisableActions];
[aLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
[CATransaction commit];
```

Comment: As @Bo and @Christopher pointed out elsewhere on this page, the property-setter `[CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];` is a cleaner way to do this.

Answer (score 12):

Also, for cleanliness' sake, use this line:

```
[CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];
```

in place of this one:

```
[CATransaction setValue:(id)kCFBooleanTrue
               forKey:kCATransactionDisableActions];
```

Comment: Good point, I don't know why Apple didn't state it like that in their help! Although this isn't really a separate answer... It should really be added to the other answer. Thanks.

Comment: Can I just add that you only need that line too.